# Unprovable integer identity involving exponentiation

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, polynomials, proof-theory

I was thinking about [Tarski's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_high_school_algebra_problem), and was wondering what happens if we have a theory $T$ with two sorts $N,Z$ with intended interpretations $\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$$\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}$$\nn,\zz$ respectively, and we axiomatize arithmetic on $\zz$, including addition, subtraction, multiplication and non-negative exponentiation as follows:

> $0,1$ are (overloaded) constants of sort $Z$ or $N$ [the context is sufficient to disambiguate them].
>
> $+,\times$ are (overloaded) binary functions with signature $(Z,Z;Z)$ or $(N,N;N)$.
>
> $-$ is a binary function with signature $(Z,Z;Z)$.
>
> Exponentiation is a binary function with signature $(Z,N;Z)$.
>
> $(Z,0,1,+,-,\times)$ is a commutative ring.
>
> $(N,0,1,+,\times)$ is a commutative semi-ring.
>
> $x^0 = 1$.   $x^1 = x$.   $1^m = 1$.
>
> $x^{m+n} = x^m \times x^n$.
>
> $x^{m \times n} = (x^m)^n$.
>
> $(x \times y)^m = x^m \times y^m$.

Then Wilkie's identity that disproves Tarski's conjecture can be proven within $T$:

$\left( (1+x)^m + (1+x+x^2)^m \right)^n \times \left( (1+x^3)^n + (1+x^2+x^4)^n \right)^m$

$\ = \left( (1+x)^m + (1+x+x^2)^m \right)^n \\ \quad \times \left( (1+x)^n \times (1-x+x^2)^n + (1+x+x^2)^n \times (1-x+x^2)^n \right)^m$

$\ = \left( (1+x)^m + (1+x+x^2)^m \right)^n \\ \quad \times \left( (1+x)^n + (1+x+x^2)^n \right)^m \times (1-x+x^2)^{n \times m}$

$\ = \left( (1+x)^n + (1+x+x^2)^n \right)^m \\ \quad \times \left( (1+x)^m + (1+x+x^2)^m \right)^n \times (1-x+x^2)^{m \times n}$

$\ = \left( (1+x)^n + (1+x+x^2)^n \right)^m \\ \quad \times \left( (1+x)^m \times (1-x+x^2)^m + (1+x+x^2)^m \times (1-x+x^2)^m \right)^n$

$\ = \left( (1+x)^n + (1+x+x^2)^n \right)^m \times \left( (1+x^3)^m + (1+x^2+x^4)^m \right)^n$.

**My questions are**:

> (1) Is every identity over $T$ that is true for $(\nn,\zz)$ provable within $T$?
>
> (1*) If so, is every identity over $T$ provable within $T$ using only the axioms and substitution?
>
> If (1) or (1*) is false, what are explicit counter-examples?

**Remarks**

[Wilkie's paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.15.9695) states that, if we extend Tarski's original equational theory by adding a function symbol for each (multivariate) polynomial over $\zz$ and adding as axioms all sentences that are true in $\nn$ and do not involve exponentiation, then the resulting equational theory proves every sentence over the original theory that is true in $\nn$.

Wilkie comments that this seems the best possible positive solution to Tarski's problem, though he says that he does not know whether the extended theory proves every sentence over itself that is true in $\nn$. He also says that there would be "great difficulties of interpretation" in extending the original theory to negative integers, but I'm not sure what he means by that since I seem to have pretty much done that above.

I asked this question [on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1766407/21820) about 1.5 years ago, but did not receive any answer or comment. So I am hoping someone here can shed some light on this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this subject matter but isn't there a background assumption that only *equational* theories are being considered? The axioms for a commutative ring include, for example, $\forall x\exists y (x+y=0)$ and this might not be considered "equational" since there's an existential quantifier?

Comment: @TimothyChow: That's if we only have the addition operation. Here I have the subtraction operation too, so that axiom you mentioned can be written as $(0-x)+x=0$ with the implicit universal quantifier. But I in fact did not restrict to equational theories in my question, because I am interested in whether all identities in this language are provable in the full first-order theory $T$. That is question (1). Only if that is true am I asking question (1*), which is whether the axioms and substitution is sufficient for all of them. I suspect the answer is yes, but have no idea why. =)

Comment: O.K.  I was mostly trying to address your implicit question about Wilkie's "great difficulties of interpretation" because I believe that Wilkie was restricting himself to equational theories.

Comment: Incidentally you could try asking Willkie himself; I think he is still active.

Comment: @TimothyChow: My best guess is that he was considering only one sort, so negative exponents would be an issue. I did not think of asking him directly, but I guess I could do so. =)